# How to grab inner text of a classname given a URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an ajax GET request here

```js
Get('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=282380', function(err, data){

});

 function Get(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
   var status = xhr.status;
   if (status === 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
   } else {
    callback(status, xhr.response);
   }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
 };
```

And I want to grab the first 3 elements of the class name "grade" and grab their inner text. How can I do this within the first Get function in the above code?

Comment: is this being done in a browser? does `www.ratemyprofessors.com` allow cross origin resource sharing? if not, then "you can't do that"™

Comment: Parse the response with a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), select your elements with a DOM method, use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods to get the texts.

Comment: `xhr.responseType = 'json'` - but the response type is not `json` and you don't **want** `json` if you want to parse HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your response type is a `text`, not a `json`. Below you can see work example.

```
Get('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=282380', function(err, data) {
  let dom = document.createElement('html');
  dom.innerHTML = data;
  let elements = Array.from(dom.getElementsByClassName('grade'));
  elements.length = 3; // if you're need only 3 first elements.
  console.log(elements);
});

function Get(url, callback, responseType = 'text') { // you can manually set type.
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.responseType = 'text';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: is there any way to use the json and text as the response type? i have two different urls one for json and one(thats in the code) that is the webpage